# Как узнать "data-key" value из тега "tr" используя Selenium Webdriver + Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Мне нужно узнать `data-key` элемента в таблице(`"Some name"` на скриншоте) который завернут в тег `<td>`. Можно это сделать используя Selenium WD + Java?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала находим родителя элемента с текстом Some name

```
By element = By.xpath("//td[.='Some name]/parent::tr");
```

Потом получаем значение атрибута **data-key** с нужного элемента

```
String attributeValue = driver.findElement(element).getAttribute("data-key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить значение атрибута с помощью selenium webdriver, мы можем использовать `element.getAttribute (attributeName)`.

Если мы попытаемся получить значение атрибута, которое не существует для тега, оно вернет нулевое значение.

Для получения списка элементов вы можете использовать

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (WebElement e: list)
  System.out.println(e.getAttribute("data-key"));
```

Comment: а можно как то узнать data-key определенного элемента имея только его тайтл? Например на скриншоте в вопросе у меня есть элемент с тайтлом ("Some name") и мне нужно узнать его data-key - в html видно что его data-key "17" но можно ли как то ч помощью Selenium его получить?

Comment: все можно получить, много вариантов, но лучше поменять исходный документ, чтобы было проще. Если вы работали с XML то должны быть в курсе как использовать серекторы.